# Azure B2C - Password Reset Screen Coming Up Twice

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-ad-b2c

I have set up Forgot Password functionality on a custom unified sign-in/sign-up screen (custom policy). It works perfectly fine, but asks the user for a new password on two screens instead of one. The flow is as follows:

1. User clicks "Forgot Your Password"
2. The flow asks for their e-mail address
3. Once e-mail address is entered and they enter a verification code, they are taken to a screen which asks for a new password (and confirmation)
4. They click continue and they AGAIN land on the screen that asks for their new password (and confirmation)
5. Regardless, they enter a new password and continue. All goes well. Password has changed

[image: choose new password screen]

They should only be asked once for a new password (and confirmation). What have I done wrong?

I followed the instructions in the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

**Update: Here is the UserJourney and SubJourneys elements of the policy. The rest is too sensitive to post**

```
    <TrustFrameworkPolicy>

<UserJourneys>

    <UserJourney Id="CustomSignUpSignIn">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ForgotPasswordExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ForgotPasswordExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ForgotPassword" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>isForgotPassword</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <JourneyList>
            <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="PasswordReset" />
          </JourneyList>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>isPasswordResetFlow</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Social" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Social" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isActiveMFASession</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="PhoneFactor-Verify" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>newPhoneNumberEntered</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWriteWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePhoneNumberUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="9" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
    <UserJourney Id="UserInfoJourney" DefaultCpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="UserInfoIssuer">
      <Authorization>
        <AuthorizationTechnicalProfiles>
          <AuthorizationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="UserInfoAuthorization" />
        </AuthorizationTechnicalProfiles>
      </Authorization>
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges UserIdentity="false">
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="UserInfoIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>
  <SubJourneys>
    <SubJourney Id="PasswordReset" Type="Call">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <!-- Validate user's email address. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Collect and persist a new password. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </SubJourney>
  </SubJourneys>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Comment: Can you share the policy?

Comment: I have updated the question. However, I have left out irrelevant and sensitive code

Answer (score 0):

I presume there is some other code that sets "isForgotPassword" and "isPasswordResetFlow".

Why have you got "PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange"? It seems to do exactly the same as "ForgotPasswordExchange".

What happens if you remove it?

Comment: One is meant to change a known password (which may have been compromised and you know it) and the other is meant for recovering/resetting a forgotten password. However, I will remove "PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" and give feedback here.

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything at all

Comment: Please see my answer. You were on the right track with the duplicate exchange. It happened to be a duplicate precondition on separate orchestration steps. I wish I could mark yours as the answer. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It turns out a previous developer imported the whole starter pack found in https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples. When I worked on the project, I followed the implementation for Forgot Password in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy. There happened to be a user journey with an orchestration step that clashed with my sub-journey, based on the precondition in:

```
`<Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>isPasswordResetFlow</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>`
```

This meant that the orchestration step was run twice because the condition was met in both. This has lost me a few days of work unfortunately. I hope it saves you some time if you stumble across this.